# Execution failed for task ':run'. > Process 'command...finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

not sure what's wrong with my build.gradle file. I'm fairly new with gradle so i'm not understanding the error. it allows my to run gradle build, gradle init, gradle tasks, etc. but the build fails when i run "gradle run"

[screenshot of my command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX8nw.png)

here's my build.gradle:

```
 plugins {
 id  'com.github.spotbugs' version '1.6.5'
 }

apply plugin: 'application'

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Definint Main class
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
mainClassName = 'main.java.main'


repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "junit:junit:4.12"

}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Configure Checkstyle
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
  // Keep checkstyle a little quieter
  ignoreFailures = true
  showViolations = false
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
  reports {
    html.enabled = true
    xml.enabled = false
  }
}
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "8.8"
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Configure SpotBugs
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The part below needs to be included for Spotbugs
 spotbugs {
   toolVersion = '3.1.1'
 }

// // To generate an HTML report instead of XML
 tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
   reports {
     xml.enabled = false
     html.enabled = true
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set your main class to

`mainClassName = 'main.java.main'`

Check whether this is correct or not. The value should be the fully qualified name of the main class i.e the class that contains the `main()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably using Scanner in your main method. Pass arguments as your code requires it using

```
gradle run --args='getItDone'
```

2. Option
In your build.gradle file include this code

```
run{
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

and run it with only gradle run in your terminal.

I am very proud you took SER 316.